# If I'm making a filter in an ASP.NET Core application, should I also inherit IFilterMetadata?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, filter, attributes, asp.net-mvc-filters

I've made an authorize filter (by inheriting the new `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter`), should I also inherit `IFilterMetadata`, and why/why not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter` already inherits `IFilterMetadata`

```
public interface IAsyncAuthorizationFilter : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IFilterMetadata
```

as [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.iasyncauthorizationfilter?view=aspnetcore-3.1) indicates `IFilterMetadata` is a "marker" interface to indicate filter types to MVC. For an example have a look at the source of [FilterCollection](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Filters/FilterCollection.cs).

Comment: Oh wow, I'm not sure how I didn't see that there. Could you please shine some light on what `IFilterMetadata` is used for?